# Uniform Continuity of $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, uniform-continuity

Is $\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$ uniformly continuous in the interval $(0,1)$? I'm having trouble evaluating the limit at $x\to 0$, hence I doubt its continuity to the right of $0$. Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: Uniformly continuous on...?

Comment: @ArpitKansal thanks for pointing out. edited the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To treat the limit as $x\to 0$ it suffices to use the mother of all inequalities about the exponential:
$$\tag1e^t\ge 1+t\qquad\text{for all }t\in\Bbb R$$
and of course $e^{t+u}=e^te^u$.
This makes 
$$e^t=(e^{t/2})^2\ge(1+\tfrac t2)^2=1+t+\frac14t^2\qquad\text{for all }t\ge-1$$
and so
$$0<\frac{e^{-\frac1x}}x=\frac1{xe^{\frac1x}}\le \frac{1}{x+1+\frac1{4x}}\qquad\text{for all }x>0.$$
As $x\to 0^+$, the upper bound tends to $0$ as well.

Comment: smooth and straightforward answer, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint/Solution:** lim$_{x \to 0+} \frac {e^{-1/x}}{x}=$lim $_{t \to \infty} te^{-t}=0$ (since exponential grows much faster than polynomial) and lim$_{x \to 1-} \frac {e^{-1/x}}{x}=e^{-1}$ exists.Hence...

Comment: how do you prove the existence of $\lim_\limits{x\to0^+}\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$

Comment: Dear @vidyarthi: i have already given the enough details.

Comment: But the Taylor expansion of $te^{-t}$ does not seem to converge as $t\to \infty$

Comment: Added more details,let me know if that works for you.

Comment: thanks, but one more question:is L'Hopital's rule inapplicable here?

Comment: @vidyarthi: it works perfectly!

Comment: but, the differentiation of numerator and denominator go on endlessly, isnt it?

Comment: lim $_{t \to \infty} te^{-t}=$lim $_{t \to \infty} \frac {t}{e^t}=0$ (By L'Hopitals)

Comment: ok, thanks, it is easier to apply L'Hopital's rule in the case $te{-t}$ than $\frac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}}{x}$

Comment: Indeed.you're welcome!